# Is it possible to regenerate my seed phrase if I have my private key?

Tags: metamask, security, private-key

The thing is I lost my seed phrase for MetaMask wallet. Luckily I had also backed up my private key. Is it possible to regenerate my "seed phrase" from my private key? It would be great if I could do it offline on my local computer because I don't want to share my private key on any online website.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can not generate seed phase from private key. But private key is everything for your account. So if had multiple accounts with some balance and you remember private keys for all addresses, then you are a lucky man.

If this is the case, you can simply create new account in metamask and get a new phrase. And then you can import your accounts to your metamask wallet using private Key.

Answer (score 0):

yes. a private key gives you access to all your funds. But it cannot generate the seed phrase it came from. Also note, when you import you private key to a new Metamask wallet, The private key will still have nothing to do with your new Metamask seed words.

Answer (score 0):

In this library that [I share here in its version for dart](https://pub.dev/documentation/bip39/latest/).

Simply, use the `mnemonicToEntropy()` method. and a private keys can be reversed.

But it does not seem to me to be the original seed that generated the key. Nor is it clear to me that it is the private key of an individual address.

It would be interesting to find out what it is doing and if it is actually useful:

Mystery solved:

What can be reversed is the decimal entropy generated by the seed. But hexadecimal entropy cannot be reversed.

```dart
  String mnemonic = await bip39.entropyToMnemonic('00000000000000000000000000000000');
    // => 'abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon about'
    
    String entropy = bip39.mnemonicToEntropy(mnemonic)
    // => String '00000000000000000000000000000000'
```